# listbox select issue

Tags: jquery

I have the code provided below. I've tried using jquery to select to make something happen but eventually what I have doesnt work or may be incorrect.

```
$("#emailList option").click(function() {
     alert("OMG");
});



<select id="emailList" multiple="multiple" name="emailList">
<option>abc@123.com</option>
</select>
```

can someone provide me with the correct way of selecting an item from my listbox?

Comment: When you say *"to make something happen"*, what do you mean. The way your code is, the `alert()` should work. *(Note that your `name` attribute is misspelled `ame`)*

Comment: @ patrick dw -- oh, what I meant when I say "to make something happen" is just me referring to like hidding a button, etc. The alert is just there to inform me I've reached the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#emailList").change(function() {
     alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method like this:

```
$("#emailList").change(function() {
  alert("Current value:" + $(this).val());
});
```

Since your `<option>` has no value, the text will be the value, so using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) works here.  The [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event doesn't execute on all browsers (IE...) for the `<option>` elements, so it's better to use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: do you have any reason why when I select just one item from the list box, it is giving me all the text item instead of the one I selected? For example, I should only be able to select one, not multiple and when I select what I want, only what I select will show in a textbox I have on that same page.

Comment: @hersh - The `multiple="multiple"` is what allows multiple selectors, just remove it to make it a single select.

Comment: how would I remove this? Thanks in advance.